# Advertising admob, installation

Tags: android, admob

How can I install immediately at all activity automatically, not just one activity at time? Is there such a method? Can it be through the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add one ad to all of your activities at once. What you should do is create in each activity an Ad request and show it whenever you need. If you want to show a banner, just load it at the beginning of your activity and show it.

Note that for each activity you'll have a different adview in a different place with a different id, which makes it impossible to "move" between activities. But it's not hard, since it's a small and simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead of having many Activities, instead having many Fragments within a single (or few Activities). Then you can have a Fragment holding your AdView that stays resident.